# Unable to write into files

Tags: python, file-io, io, python-2.7

This is a bit strange. My program isn't able to write the output to a file. Its even not showing any error. I simultaneously used standard output and found that its showing..

This is my code: (Python 2.7)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import re

def isRecycled(n,m):
    n = str(n)
    m = str(m)

    try:
        ...........
        ...........
        My Code.

    except ValueError:
        return False

ip = open("C-small-attempt0.in", "r")
op = open("output.txt", "a")
for num, eachLine in enumerate( ip.readlines()[1:] ):
    ......
    ......
    My code

    ## This is WORKING
    print "Case #%d: %d" %(num+1, count)

    ## This is NOT Working
    op.write("Case #%d: %d" %(num+1, count))
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not writing to the file.

I tried to use `"w+"`, `"w"` modes and also `writelines()` method but they didn't work.

**Edited**

However, it worked when I closed the file using `op.close()`

1. Why this is happening? (I didn't encounter it previously)
2. Does python immediately write to the file as soon as it finds `op.write()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the file for it to write to disk. Add op.close() to the end of your code.

Comment: If possible can you tell me why it happened. I wrote many small puzzles where I didn't close file... and they worked. why it happened in this case?

Comment: It is due to buffering. See the documentation on the file.write() method - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you either flush after you do changes or close the file to ensure buffers are written to disk.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing:

```
op = open("output.txt", "ab")
```

Instead of:

```
op = open("output.txt", "a")
```